# Cannot reproduce loglikelihood from GLM.jl in julia

Tags: julia

I was trying to reproduce the log-likelihood obtained from the GLM.jl package in julia. However I am not able to get to the same results.

What is wrong with my approach ?

Is it the way how I calculate the log likelihood ?

An example :

```
using Pipe
using Distributions
using GLM
using DataFrames

#simulating the data

d = Normal(0, 1)
d_epsilon = Normal(0, 0.01)

X = [ones(n) rand(d, n)]
ϵ = rand(d_epsilon, n)

β₀ = 0.1
β₁ =  - 0.2
β = [β₀ , β₁  ]

log_odds = X * β 
probs = 1 ./ (1 .+ exp.(-log_odds)) 


y = [rand(Binomial(1, p)) for p in probs] 

@pipe DataFrame(y = y , x = X[:, 2]) |>
glm(@formula(y ~ x), _ , Binomial(), LogitLink()) |> loglikelihood(_)

#we get a log likelihood of -686.72 , the coefficients obtained from the model match the generated #above so at least that is consistent

#trying to get to the log likelihood manually

function LL(; β₀ , β₁, y, X)
    
    β = [β₀ , β₁  ]

    log_odds = X * β 
    probs = 1 ./ (1 .+ exp.(-log_odds)) 

    sum(y .* log.(probs) .+ (1 .- y).*(1 .- log.(probs)))
        
end    
    

LL(β₀ = β₀ , β₁ =  β₁ , y = y, X = X)

#!!!we get a log likelihood of 447.47
```

Comment: you probably want `log.(1 .- probs)` in your formula for `LL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As observed by Bogumił Kamiński on his comment to the question there is indeed a typo on the Log Likelihood formula. The following produces consistent results:

```
sum(y .* log.(probs) .+ (1 .- y).*log.(1 .- probs))
```